# how to alter a indexed varchar(100) to text without dropping the index?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way i can modify the column **name** to **text** datatype without droping the index on the column.
or any **mysql variable** to specify **default keylength** when there is a text column for indexing while altering the datatype of the column.

```html
mysql> show create table emp1;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| emp1  | CREATE TABLE `emp1` (
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index1` (`name`),
  KEY `index2` (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> alter table emp1 modify column name text;
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'name' used in key specification without a key length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an index on a `TEXT` field without putting a key length on the index. Your current indexes don't have a key length, so you can't convert to `TEXT` until you drop those indexes.

But you can create redundant indexes so you never have a moment without an index.

```
mysql> alter table emp1 add key index1_new (name(80));
mysql> alter table emp1 drop key index1;

mysql> alter table emp1 add key index2_new (id,name(80));
mysql> alter table emp1 drop key index2;

mysql> alter table emp1 modify column name text;
```

You may be able to combine these into fewer steps too.